# Partial IP Anonymization using DTM

Tags: google-analytics, adobe-analytics

Is there a way to anonymize IP based on the URL address. The site runs across many countries, and we need to anonymize the IPs for the traffic coming from a specific country only. The subdomains are different based on the countries.

My analytics setup utilizes DTM (Dynamic Tag manager) and is configured to send data to GA (Google Analytics)

Comment: Is GA implemented as a "tool" or via custom code within some load rule ?

Comment: Eike Pierstorff: it is implemented as a tool, there is an option 'Anonymize IP addresses' within the tool configuration which can be utilized to anonymize the IPs for whole site but in this case I need country specific IP anonymization.

Comment: The problem here is that you need to anonymize based off the visitor's location, not the domain. Countries like Germany have stricter privacy policies, but it's for people who actually live there, not for particular domains. So for example, a person physically living in Germany would have to have their IP address anonymized on *all* your domains

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the "Customize Page Code" field - test the url if your user comes from a domain that requires anonymization and if so set a call to anonymizeip.

```
if(location.hostname.indexOf('some_site.de') > -1) {
ga('set' 'anonymizeip' true);
}
```

Since the custom code is run before the first pageview this should work to anonymize the IP for that domain. I admit I haven't tested this, but you can look into the network tab, if the call to the Google servers contains the parameter "&aip" then the IP is anonymized.

Here is a pirated screenshot from the Adobe documentation to show where the Customize Page Code field is (bottom of the image). Hit the "open Editor" field to insert your code.

[image]